# Looping over conditional variables

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Given the following dataframe

```
ID             Code              Quantity         Date
abc              A                  8             2020-01-31
abc              B                  5             2020-01-31
abc              C                  12            2020-01-31
def              A                  6             2020-02-29
def              B                  4             2020-03-31
ghi              A                  10            2020-01-31
```

I want to use a loop so that it becomes this:

```
ID             Date            A           B           C
abc            2020-01-31      8           5           12
def            2020-02-29      6           0           0
def            2020-02-29      0           4           0
ghi            2020-01-31      10          0           0
```

I used a lot of combinations of the for loop but unfortunately couldn't seem to make it right.

Also, not sure if there's a way to create the last dataframe already defining the right column names.

Thanks!

Comment: what programming language is this for? Adding [tag:r] based on your asking history.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Code, values_from= Quantity, 
        values_fill = list(Quantity = 0))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  ID    Date           A     B     C
#  <chr> <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
#1 abc   2020-01-31     8     5    12
#2 def   2020-02-29     6     0     0
#3 def   2020-03-31     0     4     0
#4 ghi   2020-01-31    10     0     0
```

---

Or using `spread` (from `tidyr` - if it is an earlier version)

```
df1 %>% 
    spread(Code, Quantity, fill = 0)
# ID       Date  A B  C
#1 abc 2020-01-31  8 5 12
#2 def 2020-02-29  6 0  0
#3 def 2020-03-31  0 4  0
#4 ghi 2020-01-31 10 0  0
```

If there are duplicates, then we make it unique by creating a sequence column

```
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(rn = rowid(ID, Code)) %>% 
  spread(Code, Quantity, fill = 0)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "ghi"
), Code = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A"), Quantity = c(8L, 5L, 
12L, 6L, 4L, 10L), Date = c("2020-01-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-01-31", 
"2020-02-29", "2020-03-31", "2020-01-31")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks! But pivot_wider doesn't seem to be in either dplyr or tidyr. Any other way I can obtain that function or method to deal with my problem?

Comment: @GabrielVoelcker it is from `tidyr`.  Can you check your `packageVersion('tidyr')`  if it is an earlier version, you may not have that.  Then, you could update the package

Comment: @GabrielVoelcker updated with `spread`.  CAn you test now

Comment: Thanks, @akrun Tidyr with pivot_wider is not available unless I download it from github, right? 

If I try using spread, I get the following error message: "Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.". I guess there's an issue because I have repeated values in the ID and Date columns, right?

Comment: I tried and got the following message: Error: Can't convert <double> to <list>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Values in `nitemno` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(nitemno = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(nitemno = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(nitemno = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates

I changed values_fill for values_fn and got:

Error: Can't convert a double vector to function

Comment: @GabrielVoelcker Can you please update your post with `dput` of a small dataset that shows the issue so that I can get the structure correctly.  If you check my data output from `dput`, it is reproducible